# Replace String with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to replace a part of a text using only regular expression. I want to replace password string with three stars. I don't want to use C# Regex.Replace etc. I want to do it via Regular expression. Is it possible?

(Original Text) Password : 12345

(Modified Text) Password : * * *

Comment: what is a difference between `Regex.Replace` and `regular expression` ??

Comment: You don't clear what exactly is a problem

Answer (score 1):

If you absoloutly want to do this in Regex (which isn't really smart), you can replace `.` (any character) with `*` like so:

```
string passwordString = Regex.Replace("MyPassword", ".", "*");
Console.WriteLine(passwordString);
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
string password = "MyPassword";
string passwordString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++) {
    passwordString += "*";
}
Console.WriteLine(passwordString);
```